# Selecting a particular cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel sheets. The first one has some data. The second has updated data and should be used to alter specific information on the first sheet.

For example: If I had (in the first sheet) employee wage and his number and in the second sheet also. I want to write code that will find the employee number in the second sheet and change the wage according to the wage stated in the second sheet.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need VBA, this can be done through a simple cell function: `VLOOKUP()`.

Sheet1:

```
    A      B      C         D
1 Name    No.   Wage      NewWage
---------------------------------
2 Adam    111   1000.00   [xxxx]
3 Brad    222   1300.00
4 Charly  333   2000.00
```

Sheet2:

```
    A      B      C
1 Name    No.   Wage
-----------------------
2 Adam    111   1100.00
3 Brad    222   1400.00
4 Charly  333   2100.00
```

The formula for `[xxxx]` would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!B:C;2;FALSE)
```

This looks up the new wage for each person from the second sheet. Fill the formula down.

Make sure that values in Sheet2 are sorted by employee number, or `VLOOKUP()` will not find them. Read through [the help page for VLOOKUP()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052093351033.aspx) for more details.

Comment: must be =VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!B:C;2;FALSE) ... you want to give back the 2nd column;  and if you want to convert the formulae to values, copy them all (ctrl-C), then paste-special/paste values to get rid of the link to an external file which may be disturbing, especially if you want to forward this file to other users

Comment: I almost always check to make sure VLOOKUP finds a value, else it will return an error.  =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!B:C,2,False)),"NOT FOUND",VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!B:C,2,False))

Also, if you only want an exact match, make sure you have a unique value in each table to map to and always use False for the last parameter of VLOOKUP.  If you don't use False, it will look for the closest match.

Answer (score 0):

You could Use .find:

```
dim findHere as Range
dim result as Range

set findHere = Sheet2.Range("A:A")
set result = findHere.Find("EmployeeCode")

if not result is nothing    'you get 'nothing' back if it can't find it.
result.offset(0, 2).Value = "New Wage Here"
end if
```

Or you could loop through the cells (I'd avoid this one if possible though, it can be v slow if you don't disable screen updating and automatic calculation)

```
Dim r as Range
dim finished as boolean
set r = Sheet1.Range("A1")
do
if r.Value = <ID> finished = true

while not unfinished

' do stuff with r
```

Answer (score 0):

If the employee numbers are not going to be sorted in the second sheet, you can also use MATCH in combination with INDEX:

Using Tomalak's example, the formula for [xxxx] would be:

=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C;MATCH(B2;Sheet2!B:B;0)

In effect, the MATCH statement finds the row in Column B of sheet 2 where there is an exact match for the employee ID (B2). INDEX then takes this a an offset into Column C of sheet 2 where the new wage is stored.